# Javs GUI Application MIGLayout not displaying

Tags: java, user-interface

My Java GUI application wont display data from the PersonUI.java class with the layout details im using MIGLayout in Netbeans 8.0.
All the files i n the project have no errors it wont display the GUI. May help me with displaying the MIGlayout .

```
package View;

import Model.Person;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;
/**
/**
 *
 * @author Mbano
 */import Controller.PersonBean;
public class PersonUI extends JPanel {
    private JTextField idField = new JTextField(10);
   private JTextField fNameField = new JTextField(30);

 private JTextField mNameField, lNameField, emailField, phoneField;

   private JButton createButton = new JButton("New...");
   private JButton updateButton, deleteButton, firstButton, prevButton, nextButton,
   lastButton;
 private  PersonBean bean = new PersonBean();

   public PersonUI() {
       setBorder(new TitledBorder
      (new EtchedBorder(),"Person Details"));
      setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
      add(initFields(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
      add(initButtons(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
      setFieldData(bean.moveFirst());
   }

   private JPanel initButtons() {
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 3, 3));
      panel.add(createButton);
      createButton.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
      //...
      panel.add(lastButton);
      lastButton.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
      return panel;
   }

   private JPanel initFields() {
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setLayout(new MigLayout());
      panel.add(new JLabel("ID"), "align label");
      panel.add(idField, "wrap");
      idField.setEnabled(false);
      panel.add(new JLabel("First Name"), "align label");
      panel.add(fNameField, "wrap");
      //...
      panel.add(new JLabel("Phone"), "align label");
      panel.add(phoneField, "wrap");
      return panel;
   }

   private Person getFieldData() {
      Person p = new Person();
      p.setPersonId(Integer.parseInt(idField.getText()));
      p.setFirstName(fNameField.getText());
      p.setMiddleName(mNameField.getText());
      p.setLastName(lNameField.getText());
      p.setEmail(emailField.getText());
      p.setPhone(phoneField.getText());
      return p;
   }

   private void setFieldData(Person p) {
      idField.setText(String.valueOf(p.getPersonId()));
      fNameField.setText(p.getFirstName());
      mNameField.setText(p.getMiddleName());
      lNameField.setText(p.getLastName());
      emailField.setText(p.getEmail());
      phoneField.setText(p.getPhone());
   }

   private boolean isEmptyFieldData() {
      return (fNameField.getText().trim().isEmpty()
         && mNameField.getText().trim().isEmpty()
         && lNameField.getText().trim().isEmpty()
         && emailField.getText().trim().isEmpty()
         && phoneField.getText().trim().isEmpty());
   }

   private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         Person p = getFieldData();
         switch (e.getActionCommand()) {
         case "Save":
            if (isEmptyFieldData()) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
               "Cannot create an empty record");
               return;
            }
            if (bean.create(p) != null)
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
               "New person created successfully.");
               createButton.setText("New...");
               break;
         case "New...":
            p.setPersonId(new Random()
            .nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE) + 1);
            p.setFirstName("");
            p.setMiddleName("");
            p.setLastName("");
            p.setEmail("");
            p.setPhone("");
            setFieldData(p);
            createButton.setText("Save");
            break;
         case "Update":
            if (isEmptyFieldData()) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
               "Cannot update an empty record");
               return;
            }
            if (bean.update(p) != null)
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
               null,"Person with ID:" + String.valueOf(p.getPersonId()
               + " is updated successfully"));
               break;
         case "Delete":
            if (isEmptyFieldData()) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
               "Cannot delete an empty record");
               return;
            }
            p = bean.getCurrent();
            bean.delete();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
               null,"Person with ID:"
               + String.valueOf(p.getPersonId()
               + " is deleted successfully"));
               break;
         case "First":
            setFieldData(bean.moveFirst()); break;
         case "Previous":
            setFieldData(bean.movePrevious()); break;
         case "Next":
            setFieldData(bean.moveNext()); break;
         case "Last":
            setFieldData(bean.moveLast()); break;
         default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "invalid command");
         }
      }
   }
}


package View;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
/**
 *
 * @author Mbano
 */
public class AppMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f =new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
     f.getContentPane().add(new PersonUI());
      f.setSize(600, 280);
      f.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Please change the title to include the problem you are experiencing. Also, can you describe in more detail what the problem is, and how it can be reproduced?

Comment: This site is not for you to dump a large amount of code for others to debug. If you can identify a specific piece of code where your problem exists, people can help. Read this [How do I as a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1):

Check the console for any exceptions. Try

```
new MigLayout("debug")
```

to see your Layout in debg mode.
You could also set different background colors to the differen JPanels, to see what size they have.